# How to set the sql for topic pay load in AWS IoT using Kotlin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, iot

From the documentation of Java SDK for AWS Iot they do it as following:

```
topicRulePayload.setSql("SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/<thinbg-name>/shadow/update/accepted'");
```

But in Kotlin it complains that `$aws` is unresolved. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to escape `$` symbol like this:

```
topicRulePayload.setSql("SELECT * FROM '\$aws/things/<thinbg-name>/shadow/update/accepted'");
```